# Legacy db: JoinColumnsOrFormulas and compositeId and inheritance

Tags: hibernate, playframework

I'm training to map legacy db.

```
@Entity
public class ProcessPoint extends GenericModel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "zkodid")
    public Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumnsOrFormulas({
        @JoinColumnOrFormula(column = @JoinColumn(name = "TELTXT", insertable = false, updatable = false, referencedColumnName = "id")),
        @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula = @JoinFormula(value = MeasurementLongName.TYP_TABLICY, referencedColumnName = "typ_tablicy"))
    })
    public MeasurementLongName measurementLongName;
    ...
}
```

MeasurementLongName

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value=MeasurementLongName.TYP_TABLICY)
public class MeasurementLongName extends SystemName {
    public static final String TYP_TABLICY = "23";
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "BAZA_NAZW")
@Inheritance
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="typ_tablicy")

@org.hibernate.annotations.Filter(
      name = "limitByLang",
      condition="lang_id = :currentLang"
  )
@IdClass(SystemNameId.class)
public class SystemName extends GenericModel {

@Id
public Long id;

@Id
@Column(insertable = false, updatable = false)
public int typ_tablicy;

@Column(name = "opis")
public String description;

@Override
public String toString() {
    return description;
}
```

BAZA_NAZW:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "BAZA_NAZW")
@Inheritance
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="typ_tablicy")

@org.hibernate.annotations.Filter(
  name = "limitByLang",
  condition="lang_id = :currentLang"
  )
@IdClass(SystemNameId.class)
public class SystemName extends GenericModel {

@Id
public Long id;

@Id
@Column(insertable = false, updatable = false)
public int typ_tablicy;

@Column(name = "opis")
public String description;

@Override
public String toString() {
    return description;
}
```

When I try to make a query:

```
  List<ProcessPoint> processPoints = ProcessPoint.find("station", station).fetch();
```

I got:
    A javax.persistence.PersistenceException has been caught, org.hibernate.HibernateException: SqlNode's text did not reference expected number of columns